# Пароли при регистрации и логине BCryptPasswordEncoder в Spring Security 6 не сходятся

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-security, spring-data, spring-jpa

Всем привет, уже давно решить не могу проблему, много что перечитал, так и не понял.
В общем у меня есть форма с регистрацией пользователя (Thymeleaf), данные из нее передаются в контроллер, далее пароль хешируется и данные отправляются в базу через JPA.

НО

Когда я пытаюсь войти у меня не работает авторизация, якобы неверный пароль.

В то же время если захешировать пароль на каком-то сайте и вручную вбить его в базу, то войти потом я смогу войти.

То есть если хеш вбить вручную в базу, то я могу войти. Если пройдет регистрация через мое приложение, то я не смогу зайти.

Хеш с сайта-генератора получается с одной версией алгоритма, а хеш, который генерирует мое приложение с другой версией. Поэтому я не понимаю, как так, если у меня на все приложение используется всего один бин PasswordEncoder.

**Хеш с сайта-генератора**:
$2y$10$/mZ5HhyfMTml2xj0HYEX0uQfFgHDnsdJ3IhX0pReHUTRVSDuoqAPO

**Хеш сгенерированный моим приложением**:
$2a$10$2U3MnmqMomhwWQpju1kuy.muBr7TPivlb.wn7XFilMAPJXlwaPx4.

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserService();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers("/", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/candidate/**", "/setup/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/chat/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","HEAD","USER")
            .requestMatchers("/users/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","HEAD")
            .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        ).formLogin((form) -> form
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/cards", true)
            .permitAll()
        ).logout((logout) -> logout
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
        )
        .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

}
```

**Контроллер формы регистрации**

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/setup")
class SetupController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public String setupUser(User user) {
        try {
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
            userService.save(user);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return "redirect:/setup?error=true";
        }
        return "redirect:/login";
    }

}
```

Comment: А если в Spring поменять версию BCrypt на `$2y$`? Раз сайт генерирует хэш с такой версией и всё работает, то попробуйте так сделать и в приложении.

Comment: @Byb я менял. В таком случае пароль при регистрации действительно меняется, но войти по прежнему не могу. Такое ощущение, будто разные PasswordEncoder'ы используются при регистрации и логине.

Comment: А вы пробовали сделать вместе и смену версии в программе на `$2y$`, и то, что я написал в ответе? Даже так не работает? Просто мне кажется, что это невозможно. Возьмём абстрактную ситуацию, в которой вы вашим приложением будете генерировать хеш до тех пор, пока он не совпадёт с каким-нибудь хешем, генерируемым сайтом. И при этом будто бы с сайта будет работать, а из приложения - нет, хотя это уже противоречие. Ведь хэш один и тот же и скопированный в одно и то же место (в колонку `password` в БД). Ну это так, чисто в теории, но тем не менее.

Comment: @Byb я же говорю, я так делал. не помогло. я не понимаю в чем проблема. если бы я знал, я бы тут не спрашивал.

Comment: Я могу вам в дискорде показать. Я даже менял на SHA-256. Даже так не работает

Comment: Ну, тогда по теме больше подсказать ничего не могу. Проблема интересная, будем ждать, может, кто-нибудь ещё обратит внимание на ваш вопрос. Если хотите, можете продублировать его на английский стек (на английском языке соответственно). Так как у вас тут есть аккаунт, то на английском создать его не составит труда. Помимо основного вопроса, можете там привести сразу и некоторую информацию из наших обсуждений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решена и была чертовски тупая. В `Spring Security TRACE` я увидел, что `user disabled`.

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть бин `authenticationProvider`, который использует два других бина - `userDetailsService` и `passwordEncoder` - путём явного вызова соответствующих им методов:

```
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authProvider;
}
```

Попробуйте вместо этого использовать `@Autowired`-способ:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    return authProvider;
}
```

Однажды у меня возникла проблема, очень похожая на вашу. Я тогда много времени потратил, чтобы понять, в чём ошибка, и в итоге методом научного тыка выяснил, что Spring плохо себя вёл по той причине, что в одном месте я внедрял бин (тоже `passwordEncoder`) посредством вызова метода, а в другом месте - используя `@Autowired`.

Тогда я вызов метода заменил на `@Autuwired`, и всё заработало.

Не уверен, что это поможет решить проблему, но на всякий случай можно попробовать.

Comment: не помогло, все также, не могу войти